# How to properly send Html-mail with plain text alternative from octobercms?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm using october's mail fascade to send emails. In the docs is written:

> By default, the view given to the send method is assumed to contain HTML. However, by passing an array as the first argument to the send method, you may specify a plain text view to send in addition to the HTML view:

```
Mail::send(['acme.blog::mail.html', 'acme.blog::mail.text'], $data, $callback);
```

But when I do so, the mail.text view file is ignored. For the plain text part of the message also the mail.html view file is used, containing `<br />` before linebreak.

Did I miss something? Or is this a bug?

My code:

```
$vars = ['msg' => 'Hello world'];

Mail::send(
    ['text' => 'respective.test::mails.text', 
     'html' => 'respective.test::mails.html'],  
    $vars, function($message) { 
        $message->to('name@example.com'); 
        $message->subject('Test message');
    });
```

I tried it with and without array keys. The first view file is always used for both parts. I think, this is a bug.

Comment: Can you share your code for sending the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the order of items in the array matters. The docs say:

> By default, the view given to the send method is assumed to contain
>   HTML. However, by passing an array as the first argument to the send
>   method, you may specify a plain text view to send in addition to the
>   HTML view: `Mail::send(['acme.blog::mail.html', 'acme.blog::mail.text'], $data, $callback);`

The wording suggests that the first item in the array would be `html` and the second would be `text`. Even though it isn't explicit.

---

Just in case anyone is confused by the OP's answer. The mail template file can hold header, text, html, in the one file separated by the `==`.

```
subject = "Your product has been added to OctoberCMS project"
==

Hi {{ name }},

Good news! User {{ user }} just added your product "{{ product }}" to a project.

This message was sent using no formatting (plain text)
==

<p>Hi {{ name }},</p>

<p>Good news! User {{ user }} just added your product <strong>{{ product }}</strong> to a project.</p>

<p>This email was sent using formatting (HTML)</p>
```

Comment: I think this is a bug. I've tried all variants. The first file is always used for both parts.

Answer (score 0):

On https://octobercms.com/forum/post/mail-with-plain-text-alternative mjauvin gave an answer that worked for me:

> I don't know but you can have both views (plain text and html) in the same view file.